# Finding GCD of two numbers using Euclidean algorithms?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate GCD of two numbers using Euclidean algorithm.
I am following [this resource](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euclidean-algorithms-basic-and-extended/).

**Euclidean algorithm** says that we nee to keep on subtracting smaller number from larger until the two numbers become same. Instead of subtracting they are using mod in this resource.

1. First version

   ```
    def gcd(a, b):  
        if a == 0 : 
            return b  
        return gcd(b%a, a)
   ```
2. Second version

   ```
    def gcd(a, b):
        if (b == 0):
            return a
        return gcd(b, (a % b))
   ```

In both version, the code are different but it gives me same result.I don't understand how this is working. Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each implementation of `gcd` is the mirror image of the other.

In the second example, if the variables `a` and `b` were swapped, you would get the first version. Hence these `gcd` implementations are equivalent. The only thing that changes, is the order of `a` and `b`.

This algorithms is know as [*Euclidean division*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Euclidean_division). From Wikipedia:

> At every step k, the Euclidean algorithm computes a quotient q<sub>k</sub> and remainder r<sub>k</sub> from two numbers r<sub>k-1</sub> and r<sub>k-2</sub>
>
> r<sub>k-2</sub> = q<sub>k</sub> r<sub>k-1</sub> + r<sub>k</sub>
>
> where the r<sub>k</sub> is non-negative and is strictly less than the absolute value of r<sub>k-1</sub>. The theorem which underlies the definition of the Euclidean division ensures that such a quotient and remainder always exist and are unique.
>
> In Euclid's original version of the algorithm, the quotient and remainder are found by repeated subtraction; that is, r<sub>k-1</sub> is subtracted from r<sub>k-2</sub> repeatedly until the remainder r<sub>k</sub> is smaller than r<sub>k-1</sub>. After that r<sub>k</sub> and r<sub>k-1</sub> are exchanged and the process is iterated. Euclidean division reduces all the steps between two exchanges into a single step, which is thus more efficient. Moreover, the quotients are not needed, thus one may replace Euclidean division by the modulo operation, which gives only the remainder. Thus the iteration of the Euclidean algorithm becomes simply
>
> r<sub>k</sub> = r<sub>k-2</sub> mod r<sub>k-1</sub>

### See also

- [Euclidean division (Wikipedia main article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)
- [The Euclidean Algorithm (Khan Academy)](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm)

Comment: Thanks.Can you explain any one version?

Comment: @Gnanavel See updated answer with explanation of the *Euclidean division* algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

```
def gcd1(a, b):  
    if a == 0 : 
        return b  
    return gcd(b%a, a)

def gcd2(a, b):
    if (b == 0):
        return a
    return gcd(b, (a % b))
```

The first function and the second function are exactly the same. The only difference is that the arguments `a` and `b` are swapped. Since the Euclidean Algorithm works with any order of inputs, the functions are exactly the same.

Comment: Euclidean says that we need to subtract smaller from larger.But how the mod works?I really don't unserstand.Whether we need to take mod of larger with smaller or smaller with larger.Can you explain me?

Comment: @Gnanavel If, for example, the larger number was passed to `gcd1` first, then `b%a` would evaluate to b (the smaller number) and therefore the next recursive call to `gcd1` would be `gcd1(b, a)`, reversing the order of the arguments and therefore ignoring the order.